# difference between assignments given to a variable?

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

1. false
2. 0
3. null
4. undefined
5. empty string

I use them,but I am still unaware of the **marginal difference** each prospect in the above list have.
I mostly use 0,false.But I have come across many scripts that uses undefined ,empty string.
I want to know the exact differnce between them.
I know its a silly question,but would be great If i get a small conscise answer.

Comment: Please see the `user2549366` answer.Helped me.

Comment: I think there are better answers than that link.

Answer (score 2):

It's called "truthy and falsy values" if you want to know how to refer to it.
Here is a link to explain the answer to your question: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/
(Keep in mind when reading the link at the beginning that !!(value) forces the value to be either true or false)

Answer (score 0):

The type is the difference.

`false` is a boolean, `0` is a number, `null` is an object, `undefined` is undefined, and `''` is a string.

You pick the type based on what it is being used as. For example:

```
// There is nothing wrong with this block of code
var num_cats = 7;
if(num_cats){
    // num_cats is truthy
}

// This block works but it could be made more clear
var has_cat = num_cats;
if(has_cat){
    // This would work, but it doesn't make sense. As a developer I would
    // expect that has_cat should be either true or false, not 7. 
    // One way to convert the number to a boolean would be:
        has_cat = !!num_cats 
}
```

The two most confusing falsey values are probably `null` and `undefined`.

`null` basically means that the variable exists, but it's value is unknown.
`undefined` means that the variable doesn't exist (although a variable can be explicity set to undefined like `var x = undefined;` and then the variable `x` exists but it is explicitly not being defined which means that you can treat it as though it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Only two of the values you've mentioned are what I would call designated "special values".

- `null` - In most cases this is equivalent to not applicable.
- `undefined` - The implicit version of `null`

An example for both:

```
function findByTitle(arr, title)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (arr[i].title === title) {
            return arr[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The return value of `null` indicates that the record could not be found, otherwise it's an object.

```
function increment(x, by)
{
    return x + (by || 1); // by may be undefined
}

increment(4); // 5
```

In this case, the `by` argument is not passed, so JavaScript passes it as `undefined` implicitly. I wouldn't recommend assigning this to a variable though; rather, I would use `null`.

The other values you have mentioned are not particularly special; they can be used as a starting value, such as building a string value or calculating a sum, but they're not special in their own right.

- `""` is a string
- `false` is a boolean
- `0` and `NaN` are numbers

Answer (score 0):

The list you have are 5 of the 6 "falsy" values in javascript. If you add "NaN" to that, you would have all the falsy values in javascript. So the complete "falsy" list is

```
1)0
2)""
3)false
4)undefined
5)null and
6)NaN
```

When used in a "if" statement, these all behave the same way so

```
if(0)
if("")
if(false)
if(undefined)
if(null) and
if(NaN) would behave the same
```

You asked for a short concise answer but I think the best way is just showing how it works with some basic test. Apologies for the long answer

```
//Checking if all the "falsy" values evaluate the same way in a "if" statement 
console.log("Checking if(0)");
if(0) {
   console.log(" if(0) Will not be reached");
}

console.log('Checking if("")');
if("") {
   console.log(' if("") Will not be reached');
}

console.log("Checking if(undefined)");
if(undefined) { 
   console.log("if(undefined) Will not be reached");
}

console.log("Checking if(null)");
if(null) {
   console.log("if(null) Will not be reached");
}

console.log("Checking if(Nan)");
if(NaN) {
   console.log("if(NaN) Will not be reached");
}

console.log("Checking if(false)");
if(false) {
   console.log("if(false) Will not be reached");
}
```

//Checking if all the falsy values are equal(==) to each other in a if statement

```
if(0 == "") {
  console.log('if(0 == "") is true');
}

if(0 == false) {
  console.log("if(0 == false) is true");
}

if("" == false) {
  console.log('if("" == false) is true');
}

if(0 == undefined) {
  console.log("if(0 == undefined) Will not be reached");
}

if("" == null) {
  console.log('if("" == null) Will not be reached');
}

if(undefined == null) {
  console.log("if(undefined == null) is true");
}

if(NaN == "") {
  console.log('if(NaN == "") Will not be reached');
}
```

//Checking for strictly equality between false and falsy values
    if(undefined === false) {
      console.log("Will not be reached");
    }

```
if(null === false) {
  console.log("Will not be reached");
}

if(undefined ===false) {
  console.log("Will not be reached");
}

if(0 === false) {
  console.log("Will not be reached");
}

if("" === false) {
  console.log("Will not be reached");
}

if(NaN === false) {
  console.log("Will not be reached");
}
```

What this means that though these "falsy" values might be used in a "if" statement interchangeably, they all are not equal(==) to each other(particular the set of 0,"" and false with the other three). If a stricter equals(====) is used, none of these would be equal to false, hence perhaps the classification "falsy" instead of false.